# Use of post-increment in recursion

Tags: c, post-increment

I'm new in this community, and I'm trying to understand why this recursive function not get a stack overflow,when I use the post increment (c++) in the call of the function, this passes a value of 0 (i see that when i debug), but when the next function is called, it have a value of 1.
I dont understand when the post increment is applied, and why if im passing to the function the value of 0 , in the first argument is doing s+1;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define LARGO 20

char *esta (char s[], int c){
 if(strlen(s))
    printf("\n %s", esta(s+c,c++));
 return s;
}

int main()
{
 char cad[LARGO]= {"hello"};
 int c=0;
 printf("\n %s", esta(cad,c++));
}
```

**P.S. :** Sorry if my english is not the best, It isn't my main language and i try to explain as well i could; and if it is something is not clear tell me and i change it.

Comment: Function `esta` will be called with argument `c` equal `0` forever... Since you're using recursion, this will pretty quickly result with a stack overflow.

Comment: @barak But that's just the question.  As written, `c` should equal zero forever, but for some reason it doesn't (or seems not to).  The recursion collapses normally instead of overflowing the stack.

Comment: The `s+c` expression may be evaluated before or after the `c++` expression. I think that the language standard does not define which expression inside a function-call will be evaluated first. In your case, it is probably evaluated after (`c++` and then `s+c`). But in any case, my comment above is wrong, because although argument `c` is always `0`, argument `s` **is** incremented, so the code will complete successfully. Replace `c++` with `c+1` if you want to avoid this kind of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See wikipedia [Sequence point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point). In particular item #4 gives full explanation:

> A sequence point defines any point in a computer program's execution at which it is guaranteed that all side effects of previous evaluations will **have been performed**, and no side effects from subsequent evaluations have yet been performed.
>
> 4. Before a function is entered in a function call. The **order** in which the arguments are evaluated **is not specified**, but this sequence point means that all of their side effects are complete before the function is entered.
>    In the expression f(i++) + g(j++) + h(k++), f is called with a parameter of the **original value of i**, but i is incremented **before** entering the body of f.

In other words: compiler is assigned to do a tough job here. It must pass the original value which was there *before* POST-increment (because it is how *POST*-increment works) and at the same time perform all side effects BEFORE entering the function `esta`. Among these side effects is increment the value of `c`. And, since the order in which the arguments are evaluated *is not specified* it happens so that your compiler evaluates `c++` first, and then does `s+c` which in this case means `s+1`. Hence your line is shorter and shorter and eventually `strlen(s)==0` when you exit from the recursion and print string remainders at each iteration.

Answer (score 7):

The order in which arguments are evaluated is undefined, so the compiler can choose any order it wants to. It seems in your case, it's first evaluating `c++` to 0, and then `s+c` evaluates to `s+1`.

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted.  It actually makes sense.

Comment: Additionally, there's no sequence point between the evaluation of the two arguments -- only one after all the arguments are evaluated but before the actual function call; so there's undefined behaviour for that reason too, as there would be with eg. `x = c + c++;`.  Hypothetically, the arguments could be evaluated right to left and still have the `s + c` argument mean either `s + 0` *or* `s + 1` (the side effect of the increment might happen after both arguments are evaluated, or earlier).